# Which event to use when React app finishes loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Am writing a script to be triggered when all React components has been loaded. I tried using

```
window.addEventListener('load')
```

an

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded')
```

but both don't work very well (triggered only at the beginning)

Is there another event to listen to such that it fires only after all loading has been done?

Comment: You should use `componentDidMount` on the root react component most likely.

Comment: just to add im writing a javascript widget (not in React) to cater to not just React and to be included in the <script> of the main document. but its just that with React im having an issue with due to the way its components are loaded

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, accessing something outside of React, I and I'm sure many other people will often have an outside call to something like `window.myWholeApplicationHasLoaded()` inside the `componentDidMount` of the root component. You can make a call to some function loaded in a script, or even in the HTML itself. It's not recommended to do this all over your application, but it's generally pretty safe to do it in the root component on startup.

Comment: oh you mean exposing a function in the widget such that the react developer can call in their componentDidMount ?

Comment: Effectively yes, although I would add a step of separation there. I would have a single sort of "start application" function that contains a call to the widgets exposed function, as well as any other necessary requirements for startup of your application. That way your React/Angular/Ember whatever developer, only needs to know about your "start application" function, and they wouldn't need to alter their code when additional widgets are added.

Comment: You could easily do the same thing using an event emitter. Fire out a "start application" event, and then listen for it in your widget, or globally. That way all of the framework-based developers just have to fire an event, then the non framework based developers listen to that event from wherever they want to.

Comment: am looking at ion-icon package and just by adding a script tag pointing to their cdn in the index.html and any future <ion-icon> included in any React component will be automatically replaced with the correct icon without having to run any exposed functions. I wonder how they do it. through SetInterval and constantly querying the document to check the presence of <ion-icon> tags?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionicons/blob/master/src/components/icon/icon.tsx#L96) might give you a clue. Basically, it's complicated. If you have a more specific question, feel free to narrow it down and ask again.

Comment: thanks for the tip. I realize they are using custom elements in the web api ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call external code after your React application has fully loaded, this can be done in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method of your root component:

Some global code:

```
window.runStartupTasks = () => {
  widget.doSomething();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <RootComponent />
    document.getElementById('app-container')
  );
})
```

Your root component

```
class RootComponent extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount () {
    window.runStartupTasks();
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div></div>
    )
  }
}
```